# cant see the actual map when using google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

```
<!DOCTYPE>
```

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  #map-container {
    padding: 6px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 98%;
  }

</style>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="data/weblandmark.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/markerclusterer.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(48.133333, 11.566667);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      var dataPhoto = data.weblandmarks[i];
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
          dataPhoto.longitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer (map, markers);
  }
</script>
```

I am using maps api with markercluster to show many places
I can see the zoom bar, and also the cluster generated by markercluster but not the actual map image
why?

Comment: Just set the width of #map to 100%, leave the height on auto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following CSS:

```
html { height: 100%; }
body { height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try making your map like this:

```
//The options for the google map
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //Or whatever you want
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('#map'), mapOptions);
```

This is nitpicky but it makes it alot easier to work with the map if you have to add a lot of information to it later (markers/listeners/zooms after load)

Comment: no that is not the problem..google maps show up, but only without the real image of streets inside it.

Comment: The map gets generated weird if there is to many changes attempted to be done at once, thats why making all the options before the map sometimes clears these problems up